# How to replace C1.Data.SimpleTableRow

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset, componentone

I am in the process of replacing old Component One data tools with out of the box funtionality. Now I've come across a method which uses `C1.Data.SimpleTableRow` and I can't find any equivalent method to replace the functionality. The method in question looks similar to this:

```
protected void dl_languages_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    C1.Data.SimpleTableRow lang = (C1.Data.SimpleTableRow)e.Item.DataItem;
    C1.Data.C1DataRow row = C1WebDataSet_lookup.TableViews["LANGUAGE"].Rows.Find(new object[] { lang.DataRow.ItemArray[1].ToString() });
    int Index = lang.DataRow.Ordinal;
    Index++;
    //... further processing
}
```

My first thought was to replace it with the TableRow class, but TableRow has no DataRow property. Since I can't find any documentation to SimpleTableRow I am at a total loss here.

How would I need to refactor this snippet, so I do not have to use the C1 assembly here?

Comment: Try to cast `e.Item.DataItem` to `DataRowView`.

Comment: C1 documentation referencing `SimpleTableRow`:  http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1data/C1.Data.2~C1.Data_namespace_hierarchy.html

Comment: @TimSchmelter `DataRowView` was correct. Mind adding your comment as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with componentone-controls but try to cast `e.Item.DataItem` to `DataRowView`:

```
protected void dl_languages_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView) e.Item.DataItem;
    DataRow row = rowView.Row;
    //... further processing
}
```